# Find a continuous map to show a set in $R^2$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

I want to show that the set $S = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 \leq x \leq y^2, 1 \leq y \leq 2 \}$ is connected

My first take is trying to show that $S$ is the image of a continuous function $f$ mapping some connected subset of $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ into $S$, i.e $f: E \to S$, since this would imply $f(S)$ is connected.

I just don't know how to proceed with finding the continuous map. My intuition is telling me to divide the region $S$ into two parts and try to find a piecewise function mapping into it. But I'm not so sure this approach would work

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not just give an explicit path between two points?

Comment: I haven't learned path-connectedness just yet. I'm  currently taking my first Analysis course

Comment: Do you see that $S$ is "obviously" connected? How to describe the region $S$ in plain language?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an explicit continuous function, you can take
$$\varphi:(t,y)\in [0,1]\times [1,2]\mapsto (ty^2,y)$$
which is clearly continuous and such that $\varphi([0,1]\times [1,2]))=S$, and where $[0,1]\times [1,2]$ is connected because it's a product of connected sets.